# Get HTTP ERROR: 500 on get response Json Object from glassfish Jersey Rest server

Tags: java, json, jetty, jersey-2.0

I wrote a Rest webservice in jersey. when I return from get method to client, client recieved a HTTP ERROR: 500 response if i return String Object from MyMessage class it is fine. service Class is:

```
@Path("msg")
public class MyMessage {

   @GET
   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   public MyObject  getMessage() {
       MyObject object = new MyObject();
       object.setId(1);
       object.setMessage("sdsadsadsadsa");
       return object;
   }
}
```

and class object that return from service is MyObject that wrapped message:

```
public class MyObject {
  private String message;
  private int id;

  public String getMessage() {
    return message;
  }

  public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
  }

  public int getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
  }
}
```

I use embedded jetty server and this is pom.xml :

```
<properties>
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
<maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>   
<jersey.version>2.25</jersey.version>
<jetty.version>9.2.10.v20150310</jetty.version>         
</properties>    

<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-jetty-http</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey.version}</version>
</dependency>        
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>${jetty.version}</version>
</dependency>        
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
    <version>${jetty.version}</version>
</dependency> 
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-util</artifactId>
    <version>${jetty.version}</version>
</dependency>   
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: There are some problems in your code, e.g. you create a `Response` but never use it. But this not the reason why you get status code `500`. Please edit your question and provide a stacktrace and information about the libraries that you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the following dependency in your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3</version>
</dependency>
```

by

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey.version}</version>
</dependency>
```